# how do i add two event listeners/actions to one button

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make the pause and play on "button" but am not sure how to do it. im guessing it needs to know that one click is active to switch to the other, but im not sure how to do that.

```
// Initialize variables

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var rect = document.getElementById("rect");
var polygon = document.getElementById("polygon");
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");


// Define functions

function play() {
    rect.setAttribute("class", "anim");
    polygon.setAttribute("class", "anim");
    circle.setAttribute("class", "anim");

}

function pause() {
    rect.setAttribute("class", "pause");
    polygon.setAttribute("class", "pause");
    circle.setAttribute("class", "pause");
}

// Add event listeners

button.addEventListener("click", play, false);

button2.addEventListener("click", pause, false);
```

Comment: @Jack - maybe you meant `rect.className = 'anim';`  That would be the replacement for what the OP was doing.

Comment: @jfriend00 Right, I was thinking `className` and wrote `classList` =/

Answer (score 1):

You can write a toggle handler instead:

```
function playPause()
{
    if (this.playState) {
        rect.className = polygon.className = circle.className = 'pause';
    } else {
        rect.className = polygon.className = circle.className = 'anim';
    }
    // update button text to indicate state?
    this.playState = !this.playState;
}
```

It keeps a state on the DOM element itself and switches between paused and playing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two different buttons then Try this,

```
    var isplaying = false;
    function play() {
    isplaying = true;
        rect.setAttribute("class", "anim");
        polygon.setAttribute("class", "anim");
        circle.setAttribute("class", "anim");

    }

    function pause() {
isplaying = false;
        rect.setAttribute("class", "pause");
        polygon.setAttribute("class", "pause");
        circle.setAttribute("class", "pause");
    }

    // Add event listeners

    button.addEventListener("click",function(){ if(!isplaying){
button.disable(); button2.enable(); play();}});

    button2.addEventListener("click",function(){ if(isplaying){
button2.disable(); button.enable(); pause();}});
```